# 3D manipulator disappeared from object

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I'm not sure what's happened here, but my 3D manipulator widget (for X, Y, and Z axis) has disappeared from my main object in Object Mode. It shows up in Edit Mode no problem, as well as every other object in Object Mode. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's because you locked your object:

[image]

Comment: D'oh. Well spotted. Didn't realise I'd done that. Thanks.